# tuckey urlReqwrite xss scripting escape double quotes

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, xss, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am trying to prevent cross site scripting issues. In my urlrewrite.xml, I have this -

```
<!-- XSS exploitation -->
    <rule enabled="true">
        <name>xss</name>
        <condition type="query-string" next='or'>.*&lt;script.*</condition>
        <condition type="query-string" next='or'>.*script&gt;.*</condition>
        <condition type="attribute" name='decodedQS' next='or'>.*&lt;script.*</condition>
        <condition type="attribute" name='decodedQS'>.*script&gt;.*</condition>
        <from>.*</from>
        <set type="status">400</set>
        <to>404</to>
    </rule>
```

In the above code, I am trying to send users to 404 page if they use  tag in the url Ex - http://someCompany/detail.ep?NextPage=alert(1) and the above rule works well but now I also want to send them to 404 page if they use double quotes or single quotes to invoke a script and the above code does not work. 
Ex- If somebody tries to access this url - http://localhost:8080/storefront/detail.ep?dNextPage="onsubmit="alert(1) then I want them to see--> 404. 
So I added below rule but it does not work.

```
<rule match-type="regex">
        <name>xss2</name>

        <condition type="query-string" next='or'>('[^'"]*')|("[^'"]*")|([^'"]*)</condition>
        <condition type="attribute" next='or'>('[^'"]*')|("[^'"]*")|([^'"]*)</condition>
        <from>.*</from>
        <to>null</to>
    </rule>
```

Any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: URL rewriting is the Wrong solution to the XSS problem.

Comment: So should I write a custom filter to do encoding and strip all xss chars like <,script,>, ", ' etc.?

Comment: No. Solve it exactly there where it forms a problem. In the view. In legacy JSP, use `<c:out>` or `fn:escapeXml()` to redisplay user-controlled input. In Facelets, it's already built-in.